# From standard deviation to linear regression error

Tags: regression, correlation, normal-distribution

I am trying to understand how to obtain linear regression error for a football shaped scatter plot.

Suppose I have two distributions correlated by coefficient $r$.

Moreover these two distributions have mean $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ and standard deviation $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$.

How to obtain error for linear regression starting from this data?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "error for linear regression"? Do you mean an estimate of the variance of the errors, standard errors for the coefficients, standard error of prediction, or something else?

Comment: hi whuber, the question is incomplete. I was searching for the RMS error of regression. I found it here http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~stark/SticiGui/Text/regressionErrors.htm#rms_error_of_regression . Basically it is the vertical residuals.